# Can User Groups be ordered?

Tags: user-groups

I have a site where users move through different groups based on their progress through an eLearning course. On the CP Users page the groups are listed alphabetically down the left. To get them in a meaningful order I have prefixed their names with 1, 2 etc however it would be nice not to have to do this as I re-use these names and in some places the prefix is meaningless.

Is it possible to do something like asset sources where they are 'orderable'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not currently, but not a bad idea.  I'll add it to the list.